# How to set all youtube links to open in mpv

Tags: mime-types, xdg

I would like to set my system to open all links is mpv as default ie. I click link to youtube video in IRC, mumble, discord, signal etc. it opens in mpv. I have read through xdg-open and xdg-mime but couldn't find anything useful. Is it possible to create regex-based linkhandlers?

Comment: https://codepre.com/use-mpv-to-open-youtube-and-more-videos-from-your-web-browser-firefox-chrome.html This is something I found, not sure if you had stumbled upon a better solution?

Answer (score 0):

xdg-open does not support regex. But there are replacements.
Here is a list of resource openers:
https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Default_applications

Mimeo provides regex based rules, the example for youtube to open in VLC:

`# open youtube links in VLC without opening a new instance`

`vlc --one-instance --playlist-enqueue %U ^https?://(www.)?youtube.com/watch\?.*v=`

Link to the projects page:
https://xyne.dev/projects/mimeo/